# Hardware IO Access from Interrupt Handler with Windows XP 32 bit

Tags: windows, hardware, interrupt

I have a Windows XP application that is using a driver called TVicHW32 which allows me to create an interrupt handler for OS interrupts. Currently I am using a custom ISA card in an industrial chassis with IRQ 5

The interrupt handler code is working and I can see a variable being incremented so the code that sets up and handles the interrupt is working.

The issue I have is that an IO access call fails to generate any IO activity on the ISA bus. I have an address at 0x308 that is used to trigger a start pulse on the ISA bus interface board.

If I trigger this pulse from the main code, for example, from a timer, the pulse is detected on the ISA bus and the card responds.

If I call the exact same function call to access that IO address from within the interrupt handler, nothing appears on the ISA bus. A logic analyser confirms this.

I have emailed the supplier of the driver but that can't help so I was wondering if anyone here has come across this situation and can offer a solution. This is critical to getting this project working and the only solution I can think of is to develop a custom driver with the DDK but as this requires a steep learning curve, I would hope to find an alternative solution.

Thanks
Dave...

Comment: You must be doing something wrong or I didn't understand something. If your code is executing in the kernel (IOW, already with CPL=0), there's nothing to prevent it from accessing an I/O port. The `IN`/`INS*`, `OUT`/`OUTS*` instructions should just work.

Comment: I am making calls to the library and not direct IN and OUT calls. I would have assumed the driver would take care of the IO access.

Comment: I'd like to add that I have tried a second driver (inpout32.dll) alongside the TVicHW32 and this is not generating any IO activity from calls within the interrupt handler. Outside it works.
Awaiting hardware to arrive now to test this under the debugger and do further testing.